# How many sequences of length 5 can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 2, . . . , 9 with restriction

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

How many sequences of length 5 can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 2, . . . , 9 with the property that exactly two of the 10 digits appear, e.g., 05550?

My thoughts are to determine the number of the first number first , then determine how many of the first number it can have .

$ {5 \choose 1} * 2^4$

is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

First, let us choose 2 digits out of 10 that will appear in the sequence, there are $$\binom{10}{2}$$ possibilities. Now let's form a sequence with these 2 digits. For each element of the sequence we have two choices. So there are $$2^5$$ possible combinations. However, remember that sequence such as $00000$ or $55555$ are illegal. So our final answer will be $$\binom{10}{2}\cdot(2^5-2)=1350$$